# Wikia.com pages resize themselves after loading

Tags: google-chrome, wiki

When I open a page on any Wikia ([example](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Corps_Directives)), after a few seconds the contents resize, which is a bit annoying. I've verified this in not only my default browser Chrome, but also Opera. (However, it doesn't happen in Firefox or Edge. Yes, my copy of W10 has a lot of little-used browsers installed.) Is there any way I can change this behaviour in Chrome?